# Can you create a horizontally flipped text shadow using only "text-shadow" CSS property

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

One can create shadows of text in CSS using eg `text-shadow: 5px 10px;`. However, if I want to simulate a true shadow that would generally entail flipping the shadow horizontally and possibly scaling it slightly (depending on where the assumed light source is).

My question is, is it possible to create that effect purely using the `text-shadow` property, eg something like

```
text-shadow: -100px 200px 69px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

syntax but with extra parameters for flipping. Or that's not possible and I have to resort to manually duplicating the original text and performing standard transforms on it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to add a picture to your question in order that we can see exactly what result the answers are aiming towards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with the `::after` pseudo element and the `transform` property:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.shadow{
  font: 80px sans-serif;
  text-shadow: -100px 200px 69px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.shadow::after{
  content: "Shadow Text";
    display: block;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.65);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 148deg) scale(1, 3) skew(-50deg, 0deg);
    margin: 12px 0 0 35px;
}
```

```html
<span class="shadow">Shadow Text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to duplicate the text:

```css
.box {
  font-size:30px;
  margin:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:attr(data-text);
}

.box:after {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
  /*text-shadow: 50px 20px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);*/
  filter:blur(2px);
  transform:translate(50px,20px) rotate(15deg);
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-text="some text"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, i'll accept symlink's answer because he replied first but i'll still upvote yours

Comment: @Creos I replied first :)